# iOS 15 SwiftUI 3 Picker binding is not working after changing @State value

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios15, swiftui-picker

I'm trying to use `Picker` from SwiftUI, I had this code working for iOS 14 but when I updated the project to work with iOS 15 only now it's broken and Picker is not updating anymore after assigning `@State` on view appear.

I have created a new project from zero to test it and yes I could replicate the error.

here is the code I'm using:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct Category: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    let name: String
}

let categories: [Category] = [
    Category(name: "Cat 1"),
    Category(name: "Cat 2"),
    Category(name: "Cat 3")
]

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var selectedCategory = -1
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    Picker("Category", selection: $selectedCategory) {
                        ForEach(0..<categories.count) {
                            Text(categories[$0].name)
                                .tag($0)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .onAppear {
                self.selectedCategory = 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

as you see in `onAppear` block, I'm changing `selectedCategory` value, this peace of code works well in iOS 14 but not iOS 15.

thanks

Comment: Works fine with Xcode 13 / iOS 15.

Comment: @Asperi have you been able to change and select a different category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like iOS 15 does not work like before to change the value of `State` var and send it as Binding to a Picker.

the issue is that the `State var selectedCategory`  is sent to the Picker as Binding and when I try to change the value of `selectedCategory` var on appearing the view, the binding is not being updated and the Picker value does not change when you select a different category.

What I did is to change the `selectedCategory` value in the `init` function before initializing the Picker:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct Category: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    let name: String
}

let categories: [Category] = [
    Category(name: "Cat 1"),
    Category(name: "Cat 2"),
    Category(name: "Cat 3")
]

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var selectedCategory = -1
    
    init() {
        self._selectedCategory = State(initialValue: 1)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    Picker("Category", selection: $selectedCategory) {
                        ForEach(0..<categories.count) {
                            Text(categories[$0].name)
                                .tag($0)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why do I need to assign a value on the init?
this is because in my project I need to update a Core Data record and I send the record to the view as `ObservedObject` and to change the category I need to change `selectedCategory` to have the value of the Core Data record and not the default value, by changing the value in `onAppear` the Picker get broken and does not work anymore, so the best way to do this in iOS 15 is to set the value in the `init` function and not in `onAppear`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove self.selectedCategory = 1 from onAppear and it will work fine.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var selectedCategory = 1

        var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
                Form {
                    Section {
                        Picker("Category", selection: $selectedCategory) {
                            ForEach(0..<categories.count) {
                                Text(categories[$0].name)
                                    .tag($0)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .onAppear {
//                    self.selectedCategory = 1
                }
        
            }
        }
}
```

you can set default value directly while declaring

```
@State private var selectedCategory = 1 //this will set your default value
```

Comment: I need to change the value when the view appears